# Combine .text() and .css() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, text

I'd like to use a single method in jQuery to set both text colour and text itself, as in the hypothetical / failing method:

```
$("#north_america_stat").css({
    color : northAmericaColour,
    text: northAmerica
});
```

The "text: northAmerica" is not working.

I understand it's possible to set them individually like this:

```
$("#north_america_stat").text(northAmerica);
```

then:

```
$("#north_america_stat").css({
    color : northAmericaColour, 
 });
```

but in the interest of tight code I'd like to combine the methods into one - is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with just chaining them? `$('#north_america_stat').css({color: northAmericaColour}).text(northAmerica);` ?

Comment: Can you provide a quick fiddle, please?

Comment: You do know you can chain calls in jQuery?

Comment: `text` is not a css property, so I'm not sure why you're trying to do this. Use method chaining instead.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: I do now... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is `chaining` them.

```
$('#north_america_stat')
          .css({color: northAmericaColour}) 
          .text(northAmerica);
```

Another way is using CSS `content` property.

```
$("#north_america_stat").css({
    color : northAmericaColour,
    "content": northAmerica
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not a CSS property called `text`.

If you want to use two methods on the same element in jQuery most of the time you can just `chain` method calls, like so:

```
$('#north_america_stat').css({color: northAmericaColour}).text(northAmerica);
```

This can also be done over multiple lines for readability:

```
$('#north_america_stat')
    .css({color: northAmericaColour})
    .text(northAmerica);
```

Comment: "text" also does not exist.

Comment: @mehmetseckin you can't currently chain css() and text() from what I know. For any given JQuery function, as long as it returns JQuery it can be chained. If it returns string, it cannot be chained (nothing after it can be chained)

Answer (score 2):

No such function exists yet, however, you can create one:

```
$.fn.colorAndText = function (options) {
    this.css("color", options.color || "black");
    this.text(options.text || "");
};

$("#foo").colorAndText({
    color: "green",
    text: "foobar"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YR4pM/

Note however that this is no more efficient or any easier to maintain than simply using `.css` and `.text` separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** need to create your own single call method - you can create a plugin function, e.g.

```
$.fn.colorText = function(color, text) {
    return this.css( "color", color ).text(text);
};
```

Then you can do something like

```
$('#north_america_stat').colorText('green','USA');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qW83Q/**

But this doesn't give you much advantage over normal chaining.